# Android Context Menu for any View

Tags: android, android-activity, android-menu, android-contextmenu

As far as I knew Context Menu can be registered for any view not only for ListView. Today I am trying to register context menu for an Custom ImageView. Like this:

```
// In onCreateView() method of activity
registerForContextMenu(mViewHolder.profileImageView);

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.profile_imageview:
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM_CHANGE_PICTURE, 0, "Change Picture");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM_CHANGE_PICTURE:
            //Toast.makeText(mParentActivity, "Delete " + info.position + "th item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Go to library", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

I didn't find any example of registering context menu without ListView. Would anyone give me one example or can figure out what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to write `super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);`
after all code like:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.profile_imageview:
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM_CHANGE_PICTURE, 0, "Change Picture");
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    }
}
```